# Extract a value from a SOAP Response in PHP

Tags: php, soap

I need to a value from this SOAP response.  The value is in the loginresponse / return element.  Here's the response:

```
<soap-env:envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soap-enc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<soap-env:body soap-env:encodingstyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="urn:DBCentralIntf-IDBCentral">
    <ns1:loginresponse>
        <return xsi:type="xsd:string"><**THIS IS THE VALUE I NEED**></return>
    </ns1:loginresponse>
</soap-env:body>
```

Here's how I'm trying to parse:

```
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $xml = simplexml_load_string($response, NULL, NULL, "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
    $ns = $xml->getNamespaces(true);
    $soap = $xml->children($ns['SOAP-ENV']);
    $res = $soap->Body->children($ns['NS1']);

    print_r($res->LoginResponse->Return);
```

But I get an empty object.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: So you must have tried something, so show us that so we dont think this is a do it for me question

Comment: How are you getting that response? Are you using the PHP SOAP client?

Comment: Where is your question? Did you use the native SoapClient class that should return you at least a stdClass object that should contain the value you're looking for?

Comment: Too many to list them all @RiggsFolly The one I posted in the edit was my latest and what I believe has helped me traverse into the right child element.

Comment: @Don'tPanic  using cURL

Comment: Can you get the WSDL for the web service you're using?

Comment: It seems like the removing the namespacing gets me what I need:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using cURL and attempting to parse the XML response, consider using the PHP SOAP client. [You may need to install PHP SOAP or enable it in your PHP configuration.](http://php.net/manual/en/soap.installation.php) (I'm using PHP on Windows, so I just had to uncomment `extension=php_soap.dll` in php.ini.)

If you have SOAP installed, you can get the WSDL from the provider of the web service you're using. Based on Googling this value in the XML you showed: `xmlns:ns1="urn:DBCentralIntf-IDBCentral"`, I'm guessing you can find it [here](http://sync.trams.com/dbcentral2/wsdbcentral.dll/wsdl/IDBCentral), but you'll probably have better luck finding it since you know for sure what web service you're using.

After you have the WSDL, using the PHP SOAP client is super easy:

```
$client = new SoapClient('path/to/your.wsdl');
$response = $client->Login(['username', 'password']);
$theValueYouNeed = $response->loginresponse->return;
```

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE:
Removing the namespaces clears things up a bit (although a hack).  Here my new code:

```
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$cleanxml = str_ireplace(['SOAP-ENV:', 'SOAP:'], '', $response);
$cleanxml = str_ireplace('NS1:','', $cleanxml);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($cleanxml);

echo $xml->Body->LoginResponse->return[0];
```